# fatal error C1001: TwoPhase Lookup failed on Template Function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022, poco-libraries

I use the current Release of the Poco Library (1.12.0)
With that release i was unable to build the following Program with Visual Studio 2019 and 2022 (Platformtoolset vs142 and vs143):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Poco/Any.h>

int main() {
  Poco::Any any_type;
  std::cout << "Test\n";
}
```

If i run the Compiler i got the following Error:

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\Unterlagen\Projekte\programming\cpp\_libraries\poco\Foundation\include\Poco\Any.h(124,1): fatal error C1001: Internal compiler error.
1>(compiler file 'msc1.cpp', line 1693)
1> To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
1>If possible please provide a repro here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com
1>Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
1> Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
1>C:\Users\User\Documents\Unterlagen\Projekte\programming\cpp\_libraries\poco\Foundation\include\Poco\Any.h(210): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'Poco::Placeholder<PlaceholderT,SizeV>' being compiled
1>INTERNAL COMPILER ERROR in 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX64\x64\CL.exe'
1>    Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
1>    Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
1>Done building project "Project1.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

I found out that the error occured because of the `/Zc:twoPhase` Option which is set by the `/permissive-` Option which is by default set. If i add `/Zc:twoPhase-` to disable the Two-Phase Lookup the code compiles successfully.

But i want to fix this issue inside the `Any.h`.

This is the Code which is mentioned in the Error:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename V,
        typename std::enable_if<TypeSizeGT<T, Placeholder::Size::value>::value>::type* = nullptr>
    PlaceholderT* assign(const V& value)
==> {
        erase();
        pHolder = new T(value);
        setLocal(false);
        return pHolder;
    }
```

The Arrow indicates the Line the Compiler mentioned.
I guess i need to add something to the Function Decleration but i'm not so deep inside templates.
Does anybody knows what i had to add so that MSVC is not complaining anymore??

Comment: This is a compiler bug, "internal compiler error"s always are. Report it to MSVC, but also to Poco (let them think how to work around it).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat it looks like it is really a bug. [Bug Report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/fatal-error-C1001:-Internal-compiler-err/10095155?space=62&q=djc3ho&entry=problem&sort=newest)